# How to Insert new row to Access database

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

Beginer question....learning to use ADO.net
I am trying to insert a value to the database but I am having difficulty with the syntax...Trying this code :

```
Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Z:\CompanyData.mdb"

    Using conn = New OleDbConnection(connstring)
        conn.Open()

        Dim CieName As String
        CieName = txtCieName.Text

        Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO Company (CompanyName) VALUES (@CieName)"
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CieName", CieName)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using


End Sub
```

is @CieName legal for an Access Database ?

Comment: `@CieName` is not the name of your database, it is a parameter.  `CompanyData.mdb` is the database.  Except for one thing the code looks good - you are disposing of things, using Params etc.  You can use the Textbox directly though, and it is better to use Add vs AddWithValue: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@CieName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCieName.Text`  There is no need to create a temp var like that.